# Communicate between Javascript and WebView native code in Xamarin.Forms iOS

Tags: javascript, c#, ios, xamarin.forms

OK so this works on Android... I'm stuck on iOS.

I have a custom HTML WebView which has a JavaScript event:

```
const string html= @"<button type=""button"" onClick=CSharp.SendButton(' + buttonCode + ')"">Click here</button>";
```

On Android, I have a webview custom renderer:

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Control != null)
    {
        Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        Control.AddJavascriptInterface(new JSBridge(Forms.Context), "CSharp");
    }
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
}
```

And JSBridge is a bridge between Javascript and C#:

```
public class JSBridge : Java.Lang.Object
{
    Context context;

    public JSBridge(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    [Export]
    [JavascriptInterface]
    public void SendButton(string code)
    {
        // I can pass the buttonCode here
    }
}
```

How can I do something similar on iOS?

Please note: I am aware of the HybridWebView examples on the Microsoft website: I dont want to use a seperate Javascript file, I want to fire the event from my HTML and catch it in my renderer.

Comment: You could  create a custom renderer of `WebView`  that extends the WebView to allow C# code to be invoked from JavaScript allow C# code to be invoked from JavaScript. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview .

Comment: you can create a custom renderer as in the Microsoft example. Instead of using an html file, you use whatever url you want, and just add a Navigated event to the webview in the xaml code behind CS file.